# Laravel log file permission problems

Tags: laravel, user-permissions

If there is an error when running `php artisan` command the log file will be created like this:

```
 -rw-rw-r-- 1 user www-data 2,2K Jul 28 18:08 laravel-2019-07-28.log
```

If there is an error when using app through web browser the log file will be created like this:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data 2,2K Jul 28 16:10 laravel-2019-07-28.log
```

After www-data has created the original file and if there is an error with `php artisan` command,
it will throw an error `Permission denied` because it can't write to the log

Is there a way to set default chmod for NEW created files, so that they always have `rw` for group
Or you guys have some other solution for this

To reproduce this problem:

1. delete all storage/logs/*.log files
2. call some non existing php artisan command for example: `php artisan make:xy` -> this will make an error and create a .log file
3. call route in browser /logout -> this will try to write in that same log file and will throw an error that it can't write into log 'Permission denied'

Comment: Seems like you are running artisan and your webserver as different users

Comment: of course.... How do you run your artisan commands? as www-data user???

Comment: Have you tried sudo -u www-data php artisan?

Comment: No I haven't, that would maybe create a file as www-data user, but it seems kind of pita running `sudo -u www-data php artisan` don't you think so?

Comment: For me queues failed when executed on background, because background-worker couldn't Log into the log files due to permission issue, It worked after adding "permission" => 0755,  in "config/logging.php" file,  on Log Channels (daily-channel)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Was struggling with this for a long time, and wondered the same thing as the OP, who asked:

> Is there a way to set default chmod for NEW created files, so that they always have rw for group

The answer is *YES*.

In `config/logging.php` I added `permission => 0666`, which I found in the [Laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/logging#building-log-stacks), so the config for my daily log now looks like this:

```
'daily' => [
   'driver' => 'daily',
   'path' => storage_path('logs/laravel.log'),
   'level' => 'debug',
   'days' => 14,
   'permission' => 0666,
],
```

Just to be clear, `0664` would already be enough to set group permission to `rw`, but that still resulted in permission errors.

`0666` has resolved the permission conflicts for me. Hope this helps someone!

Comment: Thank you, This worked on laravel 5.8   (I added  'permission' => 0775 )

Comment: I follow @ChardenDaxicen that's working on my CentOS

Comment: Finally, this worked on laravel 8. Thank you

Answer (score 4):

In my projects I solve this problem defining a custom logger that create a log file for each username.

1. Create the custom logger on `app/Logging/UserNamedLogger.php`:

   ```
   <?php


   namespace App\Logging;

   use Monolog\Handler\RotatingFileHandler;
   use Monolog\Handler\SyslogHandler;
   use Monolog\Logger;

   class UserNamedLogger
   {
       /**
        * Create a custom Monolog instance.
        *
        * @param  array  $config
        * @return \Monolog\Logger
        */
       public function __invoke(array $config)
       {
           $logger = new Logger('UserNamedLogger');

           // Configure Monolog to log on user named log files
           $filename = storage_path('logs/laravel-'.  posix_getpwuid(posix_geteuid())['name'] .'.log');
           $rotatingHandler = new RotatingFileHandler($filename);
           $logger->pushHandler($rotatingHandler);

           return $logger;
       }
   }
   ```
2. Edit the `config/logging.php` config file:

Inside `'channels'` key, add your custom logger:

```
    'named' => [
        'driver' => 'custom',
        'via' => App\Logging\UserNamedLogger::class,
    ],
```

And change the default logger to the `named` channel:

```
    'default' => env('LOG_CHANNEL', 'named'),
```

Now everytime that your artisan (or a scheduled job) runs, it will log on a different file that your www server do. This solves the permission issues.

Imo, this should be the default behavior for Laravel logging.

Comment: Very interesting solution, so every log file that is created is stored into separate file and there can't be collisions with user permissions?

Comment: Exactly @lewis4u. You can do some cool stuff with similar code. Consider accept this answer if you like it!

Comment: Also thanks for the editing. I wrote this on mobile, and unfortunately stackoverflow don't have a button for styling code on mobile.

Comment: Is this applicable for Laravel 5.3 also? Please, reply!

Comment: Yes, it is. I use same solution in a Laravel 5.8 application

Answer (score 1):

Change owner of the /var/www folder:

`sudo chown www-data:www-data /var/www` ( If your project is under /var/www folder )

You may replace www-data with the respective user level if you need to do for a different users like `root`.

Comment: This won't work. The problem is that the log file is daily, and if the first log message of the day is from www-data, the artisan won't be able to log anything. Same applies if artisan is the first to write a log message.

Comment: This is working for me as this command is to change the Owner of that project folder including all the files within the folder. You may try it out. And please correct me if I am still wrong.

Comment: The file is created as the user that's running php. When you run php artisan as someusername, the log file will belong to someusername, not as www-data. (php cant create files with another username, unless if it's root)

Comment: @EliasSoares has right. This will work ONLY if you already have files inside logs and not for new created ones!

Answer (score 1):

For those who don't want any additional code just go into laravel storage folder through command line/terminal and run these 3 commands:

set default group www-data

```
find logs -type d -exec chgrp www-data {} +
```

set all new files and subfolders created within the current directory inherit the group of the directory

```
find logs -type d -exec chmod g+s {} +
```

if user creates a file it will be with rw-rw-r permissions

```
sudo setfacl -R -d -m u::rw logs
```